# How to animate a Dialog window?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, animation

I'm simply trying to add some animation to my dialog window, so when user clicks on the **show button** the **Dialog should come from the top** using an animation. I tried using the animation property on the component metadata but it doesn't seem to work. A simple example of what I want is this:

[***Example Animation***](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h)

Any ideas on how to get this animation working? Thanks a lot in advance!

Here's my code:

[**PLUNKER**](https://plnkr.co/edit/MyHeNpCAdwX9edIEoKvP?p=preview)

**app.component.ts**

```
animations: [
trigger('slide-dialog', [
  state('inactive', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(10%, 0%, 0)'
  })),
  state('active', style({
    transform: 'translate3d(30%,20,0)'
  })),
  transition('active => inactive', animate('400ms ease'))
])
```

**app.template.html**

```
<p-dialog [@slide-dialog]="alertstate" header="Title" [(visible)]="display" width = '450' height = '200'
      [positionLeft]='positionLeft'
      [positionTop]='positionTop'>
      Content
</p-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace `[@slide-dialog]="alertstate"` by `[@slide-dialog]="display ? 'active' : 'inactive'"`.

Also, if you want the animation to apply when modal appears, replace

```
transition('active => inactive', animate('400ms ease'))
```

by

```
transition('inactive => active', animate('400ms ease'))
```

---

**Edit**

For a slide down transition, add this to your CSS :

```
.ui-dialog {
  top: inherit !important;
}
```

and your states should look something like :

```
        state('inactive', style({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '0px'
        })),
        state('active', style({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: '150px'
        })),
```

See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ssh1WM9T2qk0xyxEiquX?p=preview)

Comment: This is basically the out of the box animation available with p-dialog if you see the code https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/dialog/dialog.ts But I think the OP is looking for a sliding down animation like bootstrap modal.

Comment: Yes but with `[@slide-dialog]="alertstate"`, the animation will never fire... He just has to apply the good transition now.

Comment: @Antikhippe any ideas on how to get it to slide down?

Comment: @HenryDev See my *Edit* section.

Comment: @HenryDev my pleasure ;)